# How to apply colMeans to only specific rows in R?

Tags: r, mean

I want to apply colMeans() to my 'data' matrix, but in subsets.

For example, here is this (data):

```
      C1   C2   C3   C4   C5   Category
Gene1 0.07 0.11 0.05 0.07 0.07 A
Gene2 0.20 0.18 0.16 0.15 0.15 A
Gene3 0.91 0.93 0.90 0.17 0.92 C
Gene4 0.32 0.05 0.12 0.13 0.05 B
Gene5 0.44 0.53 0.46 0.03 0.47 A
Gene6 0.70 0.34 0.80 0.80 0.80 B
Gene7 0.49 0.55 0.67 0.49 0.89 B
Gene8 0.25 0.20 0.49 0.21 0.50 C
Gene9 0.10 0.10 0.05 0.11 0.09 C
```

I want to apply colMeans(data) for each category of the Genes, so for subset "A", "B" and "C" separately, and have the colMeans results as follows:

```
C1   C2   C3   C4   C5   Category
0.24 0.27 0.22 0.08 0.23 A
0.50 0.31 0.53 0.47 0.58 B
0.42 0.41 0.48 0.16 0.50 C
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use `by`, or `aggregate`. Make your example reproducible and we can talk. You can use `dput` to share data.

Comment: Use `library(dplyr);df1 %>% group_by(Category) %>% summarise_each(funs(mean))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another alternative:

```
sapply(dat[, 1:5], function(x) tapply(x, dat[, 6], mean))

         C1        C2        C3         C4        C5
A 0.2366667 0.2733333 0.2233333 0.08333333 0.2300000
B 0.5033333 0.3133333 0.5300000 0.47333333 0.5800000
C 0.4200000 0.4100000 0.4800000 0.16333333 0.5033333
```

Answer (score 2):

If it is a a `data.frame` one option is `summarise_each` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Category) %>% 
    summarise_each(funs(round(mean(.),2)))
```

However, if the dataset is `matrix`, then convert to `data.frame` with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`, do the type conversion to numeric before getting the `mean`

```
as.data.frame(mat1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE) %>%
              group_by(Category) %>%
              summarise_each(funs(round(mean(as.numeric(.)), 2)))
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your answer here.

Comment: @PoojaMandaviya  Thanks, looks like you are a fan of base R.  No issues.

Comment: Yes, that was just one line and the first one I tried. But ofcourse both methods work same :)

Comment: @PoojaMandaviya  It is just that `%>%` is so powerful that it bends the line just like light bends in  blackhole.

Comment: I have never used that before. But good that I learn now. I will try this one too, just to understand.